# Remove Ruby 2.4 and make 2.3 as default

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ruby

I have two ruby installations on my ubuntu 14.04. like this

```
nifras@Nifras-pc:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]
nifras@Nifras-pc:~$ ruby2.3 -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

How do I remove 2.4.0p0 and make ruby 2.3.3p222 as default one.

Comment: It depends. How did you install them?

Comment: Feels it's already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957730/how-can-i-uninstall-ruby-on-ubuntu - sudo apt-get purge ruby2.3

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am install ruby 2.4 from the source. How do i remove this